# find the minimum number of internal nodes of my unrooted tree in R

Tags: r

I am using the `ape` package in `R` to make a phylogeny.

```
tree1 <-read.nexus("my_unrooted_tree.nex", tree.names = NULL)
```

I want to find the minimum number of internal nodes of my unrooted tree.

Using `tree1$edge` I can could the number of ancestoral branches, but is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: Why not include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimum number of internal nodes"? The number of internal nodes is basic information included with the tree object (just type `tree$Nnode` to see the number of nodes).